# Sum of attribute value in Object List

Tags: java, arraylist, stream

I have an order which contains a list of order items List<OrderItem>. As for the order item.

```
public class OrderItem {
  private long itemId;
  private String itemName;
  private String ownerName;
  private double value;

  // all the related constructors, mutators and accessors are included.
}
```

If in this list I have the following items

```
OrderItem(1,"item1","John",12.00);
OrderItem(2,"item2","John",385.00);
OrderItem(3,"item3","John",20.00);
OrderItem(4,"item4","Doe",19.00);
```

And I want to calculate the sum of value from which the order owner's name is the same.

e.g. if owner name is "John",then return 417.00, if name is "Doe", then it is 19.00.

How can I do this through Java stream? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of `OrderItems`, we can group them by `ownerName` and do a sum as a downstream collector:

```
List<OrderItem> items = List.of(
              new OrderItem(1,"item1","John",12.00);
              new OrderItem(2,"item2","John",385.00);
              new OrderItem(3,"item3","John",20.00);
              new OrderItem(4,"item4","Doe",19.00));

Map<String, Double> result = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OrderItem::ownerName,
                 Collectors.summingDouble(OrderItem::value)));
```

From the `result` map we can get each value by the owner name:

```
System.out.println(result.get("John")); //prints 417.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this is

```
  Double sum = list.stream()
            .filter(orderItem -> orderItem.getItemName().equals("john"))
            .mapToDouble(OrderItem::getValue)
            .sum();
```

Answer (score -2):

For this question, you can simply use a for each loop to iterate over the List and, if the ownerName matches the name you're looking for, add it to your sum.

```java
double sum = 0;
for (OrderItem item: yourListName){
    if (item.getOwnerName().equals(nameYoureSearchingFor))
        sum+=item.value;
}
```

If you want to use an iterator, you can use:

```java
OrderItem item;
        double sum = 0;
        Iterator<OrderItem> iterator = list.stream().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            item = iterator.next();
            if (item.getOwnerName().equals(nameYoureLookingFor))
                sum+= item.getValue();
        }
```

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter My statement was wrong.